# Nodejs - Determine client http request network interface

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, network-programming

How would NodeJS determine which network interface the http request is coming from? Such as being eth0, eth1 etc...

Comment: The client would have to send that with the request :)

Comment: The receiving end of a TCP socket knows only the origin IP address and port, nothing about adapters or network interfaces on the other end. Only the lowest levels of networking right at the origin know anything about the physical network interface at the origin. This is part of the beauty of TCP in that the receiving end can behave the same no matter what the actual network layer looks like at the other end.